# How do I implement a bandpass filter given by this equation?

Tags: c, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm messing around with some audio stuff and the algorithm I'm trying to implement calls for a band-pass second-order FIR filter given by the equation

```
H(z) = z - z^(-1)
```

How do I implement such a bandpass filter in C?

I have raw audio data as well as an FFT on that audio data available to me, but I'm still not sure how to implement this filter, neither am I sure exactly what the equation means.

In the image below, I am trying to implement HF3:

[image: Band Pass Filter]

Comment: what is z? a floating point number? do you mean ^ as power? (z to the power -1)

Comment: @Donotalo: no - this is a Z-transform, as used in discrete time signal processing - see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform

Comment: In the algorithm the function is written with ^ as a power (e.g. z minus (z to the power of -1 ).

Comment: The algorithm doesn't seem to say whether it is time domain filtering or not.. the exact words are "The typical frequency filtering techniques are defined as " and then the equation I mention in the question above is given. One additional point-- the equation is actually written as Hf(z), not H(z).. does that mean it is suggesting frequency filtering?

Comment: @ch3rryc0ke: read the link to the Wikipedia article on Z-transforms above - `H(z)` is the Z transform of a discrete time domain filter, i.e. it implements a filter in the frequency domain using a difference equation in the discrete time domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`z^-1` is a unit (one sample) delay, `z` is one sample into the future. So your filter output at sample `i` depends on input samples at `i-1` and `i+1`. (In general you can think of `z^-n` is an n sample delay.)

If you have time domain samples in an input buffer `x[]`, and you want to filter these samples to an an output buffer `y[]`, then you would implement the given transfer function like this:

```
y[i] = x[i+1] - x[i-1]
```

E.g. in C you might process a buffer of N samples like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < N - 1; ++i)
{
    y[i] = x[i + 1] - x[i - 1];
}
```

This is a very simple first-order non-recursive high pass filter - it has zeroes at +1 and -1, so the magnitude response is zero at DC (0) and at Nyquist (Fs / 2), and it peaks at Fs / 4. So it's a very broad bandpass filter.

Comment: The more I think about it, I think the equation is describing frequency filtering, since the answer you propose is a high pass filter and the algorithm calls for a bandpass filter.. How would your answer change in that case?

Comment: @Paul R - I think it's a bandpass. If you write it as H(z) = 1-z^-2 (absorbing the shift), it has zeros at +/- 1. Look bandpass-y to me.

Comment: @mtrw: my bad - yes, I guess you could look at it as a bandpass filter, but it's a very broad one - from 0 to fs / 4 it's pretty much what I said, a differentiator or high pass filter, but the response peaks at fs / 4 and then reduces to 0 at fs / 2. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Does this image help? It shows the 3 potential filters and their graphs, I am trying to implement HF3 here http://i43.tinypic.com/29202di.jpg

Comment: @ch3rryc0ke - Paul R's answer above implement HF3. You should be good to go.

Comment: @paulR -- fs/4 meaning sampling frequency over 4? That's what I want actually (in terms of the bandpass filter)

Comment: @ch3rrycoke: yes, fs = sample rate. The peak of the filter response will be at fs / 4 and will reduce gradually to zero at DC (0 Hz) and Nyquist (fs / 2).

Answer (score 1):

A FIR filter multiplies by coefficients and accumulates a bunch of adjacent input data samples for every output data sample.  The number of coefficients will be the same as the number of z terms on the right size of your Z transform.

Note that a bandpass FIR filter usually requires a lot more terms or coefficients, roughly proportional to the steepness of the bandpass transitions desired, so 2 taps is probably too short for any useful bandpass filtering.